# Resource limit exceeded

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I executed a query and the result was: The resources occupied by CnosDB far exceed the resource limit. What is going on? Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Details are as follows:

1. start a 3meta 2 tskv CnosDB cluster:

   ```
   nohup ./target/release/cnosdb-meta --config ./meta/config/config_8901.toml &
   sleep 3
   nohup ./target/release/cnosdb-meta --config ./meta/config/config_8911.toml &
   sleep 3
   nohup ./target/release/cnosdb-meta --config ./meta/config/config_8921.toml &
   sleep 3
   curl --silent "127.0.0.1:9901/init" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}"
   sleep 2
   curl --silent "127.0.0.1:9901/add-learner" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[2, "127.0.0.1:9911"]'
   sleep 2
   curl --silent "127.0.0.1:9901/add-learner" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[3, "127.0.0.1:9921"]'
   sleep 2
   curl --silent "127.0.0.1:9901/change-membership" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[1, 2, 3]"
   sleep 2
   curl --silent "127.0.0.1:9901/metrics"
   sleep 3
   # nohup ./target/release/cnosdb run -c 8 -m 32 --config ./config/config_8902.toml &
   sleep 2
   nohup ./target/release/cnosdb_2.3.5_20240322_1536 run -c 8 -m 32 --config ./config/config_8912.toml &
   ```
2. load some data into CnosDB

   The data characteristics are as follows:

   1. column 500;
   2. data type: string+double+int;
   3. replica: double copy;
   4. Space occupied after writing to the database: 2.1TB
3. I made a limit query as follows:

   ```
   select * from testtb where time >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000' and time <= '2021-02-01 00:00:00.000000' limit 10;
   ```

The query lasted for two hours with no results, and the memory of the physical machine has been exhausted (64cpu+256GB mem)

the monitor as follow:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is the resource limit not taking effect?